# Simpler way to use groupby + transform

Tags: python, pandas

I have the df below:

```
CLASS   STUDENT
'math'  'Alex'
'math'  'Arthur'
'math'  'Katy'
'eng'   'Jack'
'eng'   'Jack'
'eng'   'Francy'
```

And need to aggregate like this:

```
CLASS   STUDENT  NEW_COL
'math'  'Alex'    'Alex', 'Arthur, Katy'
'eng'   'Jack'    'Jack','Francy'
```

I have been doing the following:

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby('CLASS').STUDENT.transform(lambda series: ', '.join(series.dropna().unique()))
df.drop('STUDENT')
df.drop_duplicates()
```

But it seems too overkill. Most probably there is a much simpler or elegant way to do this. Please assume there are other columns in the dataframe. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates().groupby('CLASS').transform(','.join)`

Comment: Please note my comment: "assume there are other columns in the dataframe"

Comment: Then use `df[['CLASS', 'STUDENT']].drop_duplicates().groupby('CLASS').transform(','.join)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('CLASS').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({
    'STUDENT': x['STUDENT'].iloc[0],
    'NEW_COL': ', '.join(x['STUDENT'])
}))
```